# Variance estimation from two gaussian distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, gaussian-process

Assume a stochastic process with observation $r$, and two hypotheses :  $X \sim (0, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim (0, \sigma^2 + \tau^2)$. When we observe/receive $r$ we  don't know which hypothesis $X$ or $Y$ it came from. Is there any way to have an estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2$ for the variance $\sigma^2$ under these conditions?

We know that the variance in one distribution can be estimated as $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$. But how to estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2$ when it is involved in two distributions?